# xmlrpc sending array argument to Bugzilla interface - "strict refs"

Tags: xml-rpc, bugzilla

I'm using XmlRpc to query my Bugzilla server, but when I execute:

```
Map params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("ids", "250");
result = (Map) client.execute("Bug.get", new Object[] { params });
```

I get:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Can't use string ("250") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at Bugzilla/WebService/Bug.pm line 76.

I've also tried [250] and {250}.
Can someone tell me how to send arguments to this method correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Vector array = new Vector();
array.addElement(250);
params.put("ids", array );
```